# React Native WebView handle or detect event from built-in script

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, webview

i cannot create listener in my html-script to because the way to navigate the html is using inside/built in script from [header source](https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/snap.js)

right now when the snap-html is close, it would return blank and i have to manually use back button, and when the redirect finish, I use render count because i have no idea how to detect the inside built in event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://app.sandbox.midtrans.com/snap/snap.js"
            data-client-key="Client key"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
```

it's like opening snap, but i need to detect when it closes/ accepting redirect finish, so i could navigate back when the snap-html is forced to close/finish.

Comment: take a look at this [post](https://medium.com/react-native-training/improving-communication-between-react-native-webviews-and-the-webpages-they-render-792c8f7db3e5).

Comment: @fayeed oh yes this is usable if only i build my own script event, which actually I didnt because the listener has made inside the source, but i have no idea how to handle it, 
because in rn, i did this in first with onMessage in webview,

i dont need to send data because i have injectedJavscript with key in ready, and the snap html would auto generate the key, and able to navigate and complete the stage because built-in source from them has a method to accept the value, which i dont need to interrupt but all i need is detecting the built in event